# Can this be considered as a repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

Suppose I have three subjects $A,B$ and $C$, and I wish to see the response of the subject to a certain treatment during two periods of time $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$. for the period $T_{1}$, if a subject, let's say $A$ has a response to this treament, then subject $B$ is going to have a response that depend on that of subject $A$. The same thing goes for subject $C$. The subjects are not Normal distributed.

Can this experment be designed as a RM-ANOVA?